# Do I need Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) even when I install Visual Studio (Desktop development with C++)

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Do I need it? If I don't need, how can I install visual studio? I mean should I install visual studio then delete the package or delete the package first, then install visual studio? And can I really delete this? Can it cause any problems?

Comment: Install Visual Studio without installing the redistributable package first. Then check and see if the redistributable package was installed along with it. The only way to know for sure is to try it.

Comment: For some reasons, my windows 7 (32 bit) operating system has already installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86). That's why I am asking that should I delete the package, then install visual studio latest version freshly or I can install Visual Studio without any problems...

Answer (score 0):

In principal, one version of the
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)
is enough, so you may install Visual Studio without it.

In practice, the versions, although named the same, may not be identical.
You may in that case see some problem when testing your compiled program,
although the chances for that happening are very slim.

If such a rare problem occurs, you may repeat the installation of
Visual Studio, this time including this package.

Note: I count 21 such packages of all types and versions
installed on my computer...
To understand more about the problem see the article:
[Why Are There So Many “Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables” Installed on My PC?](https://www.howtogeek.com/256245/why-are-there-so-many-microsoft-visual-c-redistributables-installed-on-my-pc/).